# How to make endDate's date choose only after startdate's date ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have the current code that make sure the attribute "min" is only today or after. How to make sure that when i choose `startDate`, I want to make sure `enddate` is later then the chosen `startDate`.

```
endDateTb.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
startDateTb.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Is this Webforms?

Comment: yes it is @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
DateTime startDay = DateTime.Now;

DateTime endDay = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 15 ); //
```

Comment: is there a method to go with the textbox